# Signature is INVALID after embedding CMS signature

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have taken the document hash and get it signed from a signing server which returned me the CMS signature.
Following is the code snippet:

```
Stream resultStream = new MemoryStream();

Stream readerStream = new MemoryStream(documentBytes);
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(readerStream);
byte[] signedDocument;

PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, resultStream, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfSigner.GetDocument(), true);

PdfSignatureFormField signatureFormField = (PdfSignatureFormField)acroForm.GetField("Signature1");

var signatureRects = signatureFormField.GetPdfObject().GetAsRectangle(PdfName.Rect);

pdfSigner.SetFieldName("Signature1");

ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(handSignatureBytes);

PdfSignatureAppearance sigAppearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
sigAppearance.SetContact("ContactInfo");
sigAppearance.SetLocation("Location");
sigAppearance.SetPageNumber(1);
sigAppearance.SetReason("SigningReason");
sigAppearance.SetSignatureGraphic(imageData);
sigAppearance.SetSignatureCreator("Malik");
sigAppearance.SetPageRect(signatureRects);
sigAppearance.SetReuseAppearance(false);
pdfSigner.SetSignDate(signingTime);

pdfSigner.GetDocument().GetCatalog().SetModified();

int estimatedSize = 12480;

IExternalSignatureContainer signatureContainer = new ExternalContainer(document_id);

pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(signatureContainer, estimatedSize);

signedDocument = ((MemoryStream)resultStream).ToArray();
```

Signature Container Implementation:

```
public string documentId;
public ExternalContainer(string docId)
{
    documentId = docId;
}
public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
{
    signDic.Put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
    signDic.Put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
}

public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
{
    //Send HTTP call to signing server and get CMS signature base64
    byte[] signedData = Convert.FromBase64String(result[0]);
    return signedData;
}
```

After getting signed document from IExternalSignatureContainer implementation, Adobe says:
Signature is INVALID
The Document has been altered or corrupted since the signature was applied

Comment: Probably an issue in the `Send HTTP call to signing server and get CMS signature base64` code... Can you share a signed PDF for analysis?

Comment: @mkl You can download the signed PDF from the following link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/56982a4xo85h0ua/CMS_Signature%20embedding%20Issue.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The CMS container embedded in your PDF looks ok *except* that the signed hash (in the signature's `messageDigest` attribute) is not the hash of the signed byte ranges of the PDF. Thus, either the code at `//Send HTTP call to signing server and get CMS signature base64` does not correctly forward the data to the signing server, or the signing server is defect, or indeed someone manipulated some bytes in the signed byte ranges.